# How to choose fabric and gravel for retaining wall

Tags: retaining-wall, gravel

I want to build a 15ft long retaining wall which is located at the bottom of a slope, surrounded with springs, against the fence. In searching for materials I have no idea which fabric I should choose among so many types, and what gravel is for.[image]

Comment: "springs" as in places where water comes out of the ground? Please add a photograph of the area.

Comment: Hi, the area of springs were filled with dirt and bushes are covered on. Water comes out from the bottom and flows away under the fence. I can see the fillings moved down, that is why I want to build a wall to stop.

Comment: How tall a Is this wall 15’ wall and what type of construction? The gravel helps with drainage the fabric helps to contain the dirt so it doesn’t migrate as quickly into the gravel.